# How can I convert from .csv to array/json/string in node.js

Tags: node.js, csv, express

I have a csv file I want to use in node.js/express. How can I convert the file to a variable of type array/json/string. I've tried:

```
fs.readFile('Resource.csv', function(err, data) {
    console.log(data)}
```

And also tried a number of other things I could find in SO but none work for me. The data is of multiple rows if it matters.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson

Comment: I've tried that and get: TypeError: csv(...).fromFile(...).then is not a function

Comment: Are you sure you installed and required the npm module ?

Comment: Yes. @L.Faros I am sure.

Comment: Also, if you require the module with `const csvtojson=require('csvtojson')` then you should use csvtojson(...).fromFile(...).then

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
var fs = require('fs');

var data = fs.readFileSync('Resource.csv')
    .toString() // convert Buffer to string
    .split('\n') // split string to lines
    .map(e => e.trim()) // remove white spaces for each line
    .map(e => e.split(',').map(e => e.trim())); // split each line to array

console.log(data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, '', 2)); // as json
```

Comment: I get weird characters in console. Possibly encoding is wrong.

Comment: Use `fs.readFileSync('Resource.csv', <codepage>)`. Often console doesn't work with `utf-8` (and national localizes) correctly.

Comment: This solution does not works if any field of the csv contains a ',' character.

Comment: Great solution - very neat

Comment: Nope. This solution works only with simplest csv that suitable in most cases. According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) csv values can be quoted and contain `\n`. You should use a special library for production.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on my comment (from the csvtojson doc)

Install with `npm i --save csvtojson`

Then you use the module like this :

CSV File :

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

---

JS Code :

```
const csvFilePath='<path to csv file>' // Resource.csv in your case
const csv=require('csvtojson') // Make sure you have this line in order to call functions from this modules
csv()
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.then((jsonObj)=>{
    console.log(jsonObj);
})
```

---

Output :

```
[
  {a:"1", b:"2", c:"3"},
  {a:"4", b:"5". c:"6"}
]
```