# CSV to JSON list of arrays

Tags: node.js, json, pandas, csv, csvtojson

My csv is like this, only have numbers. No headers. I have to identify the name of each column in the javascprit (node.js) code.

```
1364.00,0.15,0.36,-0.13,-3.24,-0.42,-0.15,0.90,0.00,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.04
1374.00,0.30,0.76,-0.25,-3.25,-0.41,-0.13,0.91,0.00,-0.00,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.04
1384.00,0.45,1.08,-0.35,-3.17,-0.41,-0.10,1.00,-0.00,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.07
```

node js code

```
    const csvFilePath = "test - Cópia.csv"
    
    const csvtojsonV2=require('csvtojson')
    csvtojsonV2({
        noheader:true,
        checkType:true,    
        headers:["Time","Yaw","Pitch","Roll","Heading","Ax", "Ay", "Az","Gx","Gy", "Gz", "Mx", "My", "Mz"],
        colParser:{        
            "column1": Int32Array,
            "column2":Int32Array,
            "column3":Int32Array,
            "column4":Int32Array,
            "column5":Int32Array,
            "column6":Int32Array,
            "column7":Int32Array,
            "column8":Int32Array,
            "column9":Int32Array,
            "column10":Int32Array,
            "column11":Int32Array,
            "column12":Int32Array,
            "column13":Int32Array,
            "column14":Int32Array},
            
        
    })
    .fromFile(csvFilePath)
    .then((json) => {
        console.log(json)  
    })
```

and the result that i obtain with the code above is this json:

```
[
      {
        Time: 1364,
        Yaw: 0.15,
        Pitch: 0.36,
        Roll: -0.13,
        Heading: -3.24,
        Ax: -0.42,
        Ay: -0.15,
        Az: 0.9,
        Gx: 0,
        Gy: -0.01,
        Gz: 0.02,
        Mx: 0.26,
        My: 0.01,
        Mz: -0.04
      },
      {
        Time: 1374,
        Yaw: 0.3,
        Pitch: 0.76,
        Roll: -0.25,
        Heading: -3.25,
        Ax: -0.41,
        Ay: -0.13,
        Az: 0.91,
        Gx: 0,
        Gy: -0,
        Gz: 0.02,
        Mx: 0.26,
        My: 0.01,
        Mz: -0.04
      },
      {
        Time: 1384,
        Yaw: 0.45,
        Pitch: 1.08,
        Roll: -0.35,
        Heading: -3.17,
        Ax: -0.41,
        Ay: -0.1,
        Az: 1,
        Gx: -0,
        Gy: -0.01,
        Gz: 0.02,
        Mx: 0.26,
        My: 0.01,
        Mz: -0.07
      }
    ]
```

I want a little different, like this(bewlow: Each Column a dictionary of arrays.

```
{"Time": [1364.0, 1374.0, 1384.0], 
"Yaw": [0.15, 0.3, 0.45], 
"Pitch": [0.36, 0.76, 1.08], 
"Heading": [-0.13, -0.25, -0.35], 
"Roll": [-3.24, -3.25, -3.17], 
"Ax": [-0.42, -0.41, -0.41], 
"Ay": [-0.15, -0.13, -0.1], 
"Az": [0.9, 0.91, 1.0], 
"Gx": [0.0, 0.0, -0.0], 
"Gy": [-0.01, -0.0, -0.01], 
"Gz": [0.02, 0.02, 0.02], 
"Mx": [0.26, 0.26, 0.26], 
"My": [0.01, 0.01, 0.01], 
"Mz": [-0.04, -0.04, -0.07]}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! I encourage you to read this post on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a great question. Specifically, questions asking how to translate from one language to another [are discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265834/3888719) on the site. It seems like you have a perfectly good question about how to do something in Javascript. Please describe the problem, what you've tried (in JavaScript) and what you'd like to see, and remove the python content.

Comment: thanks @MichaelDelgado. will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First method

Using your code, which uses the `csvtojson` library, you can just add this:

```js
    const csvFilePath = "test - Cópia.csv"
    
    const csvtojsonV2=require('csvtojson')
    csvtojsonV2({
        noheader:true,
        checkType:true,    
        headers:["Time","Yaw","Pitch","Roll","Heading","Ax", "Ay", "Az","Gx","Gy", "Gz", "Mx", "My", "Mz"],
        colParser:{        
            "column1": Int32Array,
            "column2":Int32Array,
            "column3":Int32Array,
            "column4":Int32Array,
            "column5":Int32Array,
            "column6":Int32Array,
            "column7":Int32Array,
            "column8":Int32Array,
            "column9":Int32Array,
            "column10":Int32Array,
            "column11":Int32Array,
            "column12":Int32Array,
            "column13":Int32Array,
            "column14":Int32Array},
            
        
    })
    .fromFile(csvFilePath)
    .then((json) => {
       const RESULT = json.reduce((acc, v, i) => {
          for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(v)) {
            if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = [];
            acc[key].push(value);
          }
          return acc;
        }, {});
       console.log(RESULT)
    })
```

What it does is to accumulate the data in `acc` variable, using each rows' keys these keys being the header, as you can see in `acc[key].push(value)`, the `if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = []` is to make sure the heading is initializied with an empty array in the `acc` variable (accumulator);

### Second method

This doesn't use any library:

```js
// Arbitrary data (from you example).
const DATA = `1364.00,0.15,0.36,-0.13,-3.24,-0.42,-0.15,0.90,0.00,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.04
1374.00,0.30,0.76,-0.25,-3.25,-0.41,-0.13,0.91,0.00,-0.00,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.04
1384.00,0.45,1.08,-0.35,-3.17,-0.41,-0.10,1.00,-0.00,-0.01,0.02,0.26,0.01,-0.07
`.trim().split('\n').map(row => row.split(','));

const HEADERS = ["Time", "Yaw", "Pitch", "Roll", "Heading", "Ax", "Ay", "Az", "Gx", "Gy", "Gz", "Mx", "My", "Mz"];

const RESULT = {};

// Assign every heading to the result.
for (const HEADING of HEADERS) RESULT[HEADING] = [];

DATA.map(row =>
  // Each row → each column, number of columns === number of headers
  row.map((column, i) =>
    RESULT[HEADERS[i]]
    .push(Number(column))
  )
);

console.log(RESULT);
```

Explanation of each step:

1. Assuming that the CSV's contents separates rows with "\n" and the preferred column separator is ",", I set up an arbitrary data contents;
2. A constant `HEADERS` is created, the headers must be the same length of the CSV's data columns;
3. A constant `RESULT` is created, this will store the result of the parsed data to JSON.
4. We initialize the keys of `RESULT` with the defined `HEADERS` with an empty array;
5. We map the data from each **row** then each **column**, using the column's index to refer to the current heading in our `HEADERS` array, since the length of the columns are expected to be equal to the length of the `HEADERS` constant.

If you must keep the trailing zeroes (e.g.: 15.00) of the numbers, then you can just remove `Number()` method from `Number(column)` inside the `.push()` method before inserting into the result array.

Comment: To read a CSV file in NodeJS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031531/how-can-i-convert-from-csv-to-array-json-string-in-node-js#53031629

Comment: thanks a lot @rick stanley. I'm using a library because csv files are very big. With 70000 rows. I find that with library is much faster to parse and transform the csv to json